# How to measure Performance of data processing in Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are running a project in Google cloud platform and using pubsub,dataflow & Bigquery products. How do we calculate performance of one message(data) processing that flows from pubsub->dataflow->bigquery?

Comment: Does PerfKit has capability to measure the performance of data flowing?

Comment: for streaming/batch dataflow jobs

Answer (score 0):

There can not be anything that can used to measure the performance over this pipeline. What you can do is to note the submit time of each process in the pipeline and then measure the measure the time for each record processed.

Answer (score 0):

Measure GCP performance is very difficult but there are some approaches. As you commented, PerfKit is documented option. It has two variants: PerfKit Benchmarker and PerfKit Explorer

See [Measure and compare performance](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/measure-compare-performance) for more details.